# get-itemPropertyValue doesn't bind Path when using \\?\UNC\ (long unc path) in start-job scriptblock

Tags: powershell, unc, character-limit

I'm trying to multithread this

```
$var3 = Get-ItemPropertyValue $var2 -Name fullName,CreationTime,lastAccessTime,LastWriteTime,length;
```

by replacing it with:

```
$var3 = forEach($file in $var2) {
        start-job -name "bla" -scriptblock {Get-ItemPropertyValue $file.FullName -Name fullName,LastWriteTime,CreationTime,lastAccessTime,length} | out-null
    }
```

where `$var2` holds a list of files retrieved via `gci`.

This works for normal paths, but not for long UNC Paths prefixed by `\\?\UNC\`.

The long path itself works fine with the `get-itemPropertyValue '\\?\UNC\some long path in Webdav'` but doesn't as soon as I put it into the scriptBlock from start-job.

The errormessage says (in german):

> "Das Argument für den Parameter "Path" kann nicht überprüft werden. Das Argument ist NULL oder leer. Geben Sie ein Argument an, das nicht NULL oder leer ist, und führen Sie den Befehl erneut
> aus.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ItemPropertyValue], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyValueCommand
> + PSComputerName        : localhost

When I try to bind it with `get-itemPropertyValue -LocalPath '\\?\UNC\some long path in Webdav'` it also fails but with this Errormessage:

> Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "LiteralPath" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ItemPropertyValue], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyValueCommand
> + PSComputerName        : localhost

Can anyone please check, if it is true, that this doesn't work, or show a running example otherwise? I'm running PS Version 5.1 and have to use this version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `$file > $using:file`. The scope of a job is not the same as your current scope.

Comment: I also encourage you to divide the array you're looping through into chunks and passing that chunk to a job instead of file by file as it will be a lot slower than a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Santiago is right about scoping, and his advise on threading blocks of files at a time is solid, but if you got the list of files via `Get-ChildItem` shouldn't you already have the data you're trying to multi-thread? Isn't this essentially the same as `$var3 = $var2 | Select fullName,CreationTime,lastAccessTime,LastWriteTime,length`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, this really solves my underlying problem and i'm wondering why I ended up using get-itemPropertyValue in the first place. Is there also a switch to get rid of the field captions in the output?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, that works and is the proper answer to the question :) Can you please elaborate a bit on the scope part and write an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, *the scope of a job is not the same as your current scope*, meaning that, the jobs you start cannot see variables defined outside it's scope (i.e.: `$file`). You need to pass the variables to it's scope, either with `$using:foo` or with `-ArgumentList`:

```
$props = 'FullName','LastWriteTime','CreationTime','LastAccessTime','Length'

$var3 = forEach($file in (Get-ChildItem -File))
{
    Start-Job -Name "bla" -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ItemPropertyValue $using:file.FullName -Name $using:props
    }
}

$var3 | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

# OR

$var3 = forEach($file in (Get-ChildItem -File))
{
    Start-Job -Name "bla" -ScriptBlock {
        param($file, $props)

        Get-ItemPropertyValue $file.FullName -Name $props
    } -ArgumentList $file, $props
}

$var3 | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

As for [@TheMadTechnician's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469635/get-itempropertyvalue-doesnt-bind-path-when-using-unc-long-unc-path-in-s?noredirect=1#comment121013783_68469635) comment, he is right, there is no need to use `Get-ItemProperty` if you're already calling `Get-ChildItem` but for the sake of explaining what I meant in my next comment: *...divide the array you're looping through into chunks and passing that chunk to a job instead of file by file as it...*, starting a job for each file would be not only many times slower than a normal `foreach` loop but also would consume a lot of memory. `Start-Job` in general is slower than a linear loop, if you're looking for a multithread alternative, you should be looking at either [RunSpace](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/) or [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.1) from the ThreadJob Module. I have done some testing comparing the performance [**Linear Loops vs ThreadJob vs Runspace**](https://github.com/santysq/Linear-Loops-vs-ThreadJob-vs-Runspace) when looping through local directories and files, you can download the script from my GitHub if you're interested (bear in mind, it requires having the ThreadJob module installed).

- To show you a simple example of what I meant by passing chunk to a job, first store all directories in a variable and define the number of threads you want to use (number of jobs running at the same time):

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem . -Directory -Recurse
$numberOfThreads = 10
```

- Then we divide this array of directories into the the number of threads, 10 in this case:

```
$groupSize = [math]::Ceiling($directories.Count / $numberOfThreads)
$counter = [pscustomobject]@{ Value = 0 }
$groups = $directories | Group-Object -Property {
    [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $groupSize)
}
```

- Lastly, we pass these 10 chunks of folders to each job. Each job will be counting the number of files on each folder:

```
$var3 = foreach($chunk in $groups)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        $folders = $using:chunk.Group.FullName
        foreach($folder in $folders)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                DirectoryFullName = $folder
                NumberOfFiles = (Get-ChildItem $folder -File).count
            }
        }
    }
}

$result = $var3 | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob |
Sort-Object NumberOfFiles -Descending |
Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID,PSSourceJobInstanceId
```

If you try this on your computer, you would be getting something like:

```
DirectoryFullName      NumberOfFiles
-----------------      -------------
X:\ExampleUser\Folder0          1954
X:\ExampleUser\Folder1           649
X:\ExampleUser\Folder2            64
X:\ExampleUser\Folder3            36
X:\ExampleUser\Folder4            23
X:\ExampleUser\Folder5            16
X:\ExampleUser\Folder6            15
X:\ExampleUser\Folder7            15
X:\ExampleUser\Folder8            12
X:\ExampleUser\Folder9            10
```